# Copy Value to Another Cell at a specific time that is different each day

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to copy a cell that contains an ongoing/increasing value of numbers at 11:59.59 pm to another cell (The number only, not the increasing value) and then on the next day do the same thing, but have it save to the next cell below it?  For instance.  Day 1 Would save to H10, Day 2 H11, Day 3 H13, etc for the month.  Then at the end of the month, it would export that row to another excel file and save it with a timestamp?

Is that possible?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already know how to find the last row in a column, you can invoke `Application.Wait "23:59:59"` to have the running vba script wait until the stated time and then have it copy your cell values, but it's an incredibly unreliable method--if Microsoft decides to restart your computer and install a bunch of useless updates (and set your program defaults back to whatever MS wants them to be GRRRR), then the workbook wouldn't be open.

I believe it would also prevent you from using Excel the entire time the script was executing. If you can, it would make more sense to record a timestamp when the "increasing value of numbers" is recorded and then only select from those values whose timestamp corresponds to 11:59.59 pm.

Better yet, do the whole thing in SQL Server ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is how to run on time :

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'Run YourOtherSub at midnight
Application.OnTime TimeValue("23:59:59"), "YourOtherSub"
End Sub
```

You make your macro as YourOtherSub or change its name